# EditText strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In Android (Java) I have a dynamically background colored TextView in my app. To make the background color of EditText"primaryColor" I wrote such line of code:

```
public void setEditTextThingsColor(EditText view) {
    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(colorPrimary, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    (...some other settings...)
}
```

where `view` is my EditText element, `primaryColor` is downloaded from database.

I have tested it on API 27 and API 19. It works fine on API 27. On API 19 it doesn't.

However, when I wrote such code:

```
public void setEditTextThingsColor(EditText view) {
    Drawable temp = view.getBackground();
    temp.setColorFilter(colorPrimary, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    view.setBackground(temp);
    (...some other settings...)
}
```

it works fine on both APIs.

What is the reason of such behaviour?

Can API 19 find my element immutable or so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are few changes in `setColorFilter()` method. Not sure if it is root-cause of this behaviour. Need to look more into it. Below is code from both versions

From [KitKat](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java)

```
440    /**
441     * Specify a color and porterduff mode to be the colorfilter for this
442     * drawable.
443     */
444    public void setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode) {
445        setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, mode));
446    }
```

and from [Orio](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java)

```
582    /**
583     * Specify a color and Porter-Duff mode to be the color filter for this
584     * drawable.
585     * <p>
586     * Convenience for {@link #setColorFilter(ColorFilter)} which constructs a
587     * {@link PorterDuffColorFilter}.
588     * </p>
589     * <p class="note"><strong>Note:</strong> Setting a color filter disables
590     * {@link #setTintList(ColorStateList) tint}.
591     * </p>
592     */
593    public void setColorFilter(@ColorInt int color, @NonNull PorterDuff.Mode mode) {
594        if (getColorFilter() instanceof PorterDuffColorFilter) {
595            PorterDuffColorFilter existing = (PorterDuffColorFilter) getColorFilter();
596            if (existing.getColor() == color && existing.getMode() == mode) {
597                return;
598            }
599        }
600        setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, mode));
601    }
```

---

Instead-of using [android.widget.**EditText**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText), use [android.support.v7.widget.**AppCompatEditText**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText) to make common behaviour on all versions.